# How to get time in milliseconds from a string in android?

Tags: android, string, date, calendar, alarmmanager

My app is very simple, it consist of a string variable which consists of both date and time in it, from that string i need to fetch only time and convert it into milliseconds, so that i can pass that milliseconds to alarm manager to trigger alarm.

Here is the code of my MainActivity looks like:

```
   try {
        String string = "Mon, 10 Mar 2017 03:26:00 p.m.";
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(string.substring(17, 19)));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(string.substring(20, 22)));
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, string.contains("a.m.") ? 0 : 1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cal: " + calendar.getTime()+ " , milli sec: "+calendar.getTimeInMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exe: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

when i'm printing **calendar.getTime** i'm getting both date and time i.e; **Tue Mar 14 15:26:45 GMT+05:30 2017**, instead of that i need to get **15:26:45** value and convert that value into milli seconds.

Comment: c.getTimeInMillis()

Comment: when i we use **calendar.getTimeInMillis()** we will get **15:26:45** in milliseconds not the entire right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
try {
    String string = "Mon, 10 Mar 2017 03:26:00 p.m.";
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(string.substring(17, 19)));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(string.substring(20, 22)));
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, string.contains("a.m.") ? 0 : 1);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cal: " + dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime())+ " , milli sec: "+calendar.getTimeInMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exe: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I have implemented your code, but when i print **dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime())** it is prinitng current system time.

Comment: Replace HOUR_OF_DAY with HOUR

Comment: Thanx @shmakova. You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` to get milliseconds.

Comment: when i we use **calendar.getTimeInMillis()** we will get **15:26:45** in milliseconds not the entire thing in milliseconds right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    String inputString = "00:01:30.500";

    Date date = sdf.parse("1970-01-01 " + inputString);
    System.out.println("in milliseconds: " + date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code:**

```
try {
    String string = "Mon, 10 Mar 2017 03:26:00 p.m.";
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(string.substring(17, 19)));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(string.substring(20, 22)));
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, string.contains("a.m.") ? 0 : 1);
    calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String time = sdf.format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
    long timeinmili=0;
    try {
        Date date1 = sdf.parse(time);
        timeinmili = date1.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Time in Mili Seconds :"+timeinmili );
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: **time** string is printing current system time yar.